# Sparse matrix problem(there is a problem in my scan_matrix function)

Tags: c, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to write a matrix to sparse matrix conversion program.
But, there is a problem in my scan_matrix function.I couldn't figure out where is the problem.According to Nemiver(debugging program) problem is in my fscanf call...
My piece of code:

```
void scan_matrix(FILE *inp, struct sparse_m mysparse[], int *place_p)
{
    int matrix[9][9];
    int row,column,place=0;
    for(column=0;column<9;column++){
        for(row=0;row<9;row++){
            fscanf(inp, "%d", &matrix[row][column]);
        }
    }
    for(column=0;column<9;column++){
        for(row=0;row<9;row++){
            if( matrix[row][column] != 0 ) {
                mysparse[place++].row = row;
                mysparse[place++].column = column;
                mysparse[place++].value = matrix[row][column];
            }
        }
    }
    *place_p = place;
}
```

and my two dimensional matrix:

```
64  -16     0   -16     0     0     0     0     0
-16  64   -16     0   -16     0     0     0     0
0   -16    64     0     0   -16     0     0     0
-16   0     0    64   -16     0   -16     0     0
0   -16     0   -16    64   -16     0   -16     0
0     0   -16     0   -16    64     0     0   -16
0     0     0   -16     0     0    64   -16     0
0     0     0     0   -16     0   -16    64   -16
0     0     0     0     0   -16     0   -16    64
```

The output must be something like this;

```
(3, 0)  64
(4, 1)  -16
(5, 2)  -16
(6, 3)  -16
(7, 4)  64
(8, 5)  -16
(7, 6)  -16
(8, 7)  -16
(8, 8)  64
```

my full code;

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct sparse_m {
    int row,
        column,
        value;
};
void write_sparse(FILE *outp, struct sparse_m mysparse[], int c);
void scan_matrix(FILE *inp, struct sparse_m mysparse[],int *place_p);

int main(void)
{
    int a = 0;
    FILE *inp_txt;
    FILE *outp_txt;
    inp_txt = fopen("s_matrix.dat", "r");
    outp_txt = fopen("sparse.dat", "w");
    struct sparse_m mys[10];
    scan_matrix(inp_txt, mys,&a);
    write_sparse(outp_txt,mys,a);

    return(0);
}
void scan_matrix(FILE *inp, struct sparse_m mysparse[], int *place_p)
{
    int matrix[9][9];
    int row,column,place=0;
    for(column=0;column<9;column++){
        for(row=0;row<9;row++){
            fscanf(inp, "%d", &matrix[row][column]);
        }
    }
    for(column=0;column<9;column++){
        for(row=0;row<9;row++){
            if( matrix[row][column] != 0 ) {
                mysparse[place++].row = row;
                mysparse[place++].column = column;
                mysparse[place++].value = matrix[row][column];
            }
        }
    }
    *place_p = place;
}

void write_sparse(FILE *outp, struct sparse_m mysparse[], int c)
{
    int i;
    printf("%d---", c);
    for(i=0;i<c;i++){
        fprintf(outp, "(%d, %d)  %d\n", mysparse[i].row,
                                        mysparse[i].column,
                                        mysparse[i].value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mysparse[place++].row = row;
mysparse[place++].column = column;
mysparse[place++].value = matrix[row][column];
```

You are incrementing `place` three times.

Comment: +1 Didn't spot that one! I must say this is an excellent illustration of why this idiom is a bad idea and the language would be better off without these silly operators.

Comment: And also there was problem in my main function 

    struct sparse_m mys[10];

According to 9X9 two-dimensional array,There must be a room more than 10,
so I changed it with this

    struct sparse_m mys[81];
and made your suggests...
Now it gives proper output...

Comment: @guguk I hope you fixed the row/column loop order too! You are just getting lucky at the moment because your array is symmetric.

Answer (score 2):

You've got your row/column loops the wrong way round.  Instead of:

```
for(column=0;column<9;column++){
    for(row=0;row<9;row++){
```

you need:

```
for(row=0;row<9;row++){
    for(column=0;column<9;column++){
```

Your code was effectively transposing the matrix.  In fact for the input you give this doesn't matter since the matrix is symmetric and so you get away with it for now.

Also see @Banthar's answer for another mistake!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
mysparse[place++].row = row;
mysparse[place++].column = column;
mysparse[place++].value = matrix[row][column];
```

You're incrementing the myspase index you're writing to with every assignment above. Change it to the following:

```
mysparse[place].row = row;
mysparse[place].column = column;
mysparse[place].value = matrix[row][column];
place++;
```

Comment: this duplicates @Banthar's answer. And you forgot to increment place at all!

Comment: @David Hefferman: I began writing the answer when there were no answers visible yet, but after submission he beat me to it. No ideas why his answer didn't show up, it's been a 15min difference. Alas, you don't have to upvote.